# reference errors Using ML.net in .Net Framework 4 project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard-2.0, ml.net

I'm trying to add ML.net to a Framework 4 project.
Can't seem to be able to combine these two without nagging netstandard reference errors.
Browsed the net for hours now but couldn't fine a walk-thru or example project.

Is there someone who knows how to do that?

Comment: According to their [documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning#using-mlnet-packages), it works only with .NET FW 4.6.1, however 4.7.2 is recommended

Comment: What errors are you getting from this? And what version of ML.NET did you try?

Comment: @Jon:
Error : Unrecognized Guid format
Probable cause : a lib with Runtimeversion v4.0.30319

Answer (score 0):

What is the version target of your Framework 4 project? If you target your project to .NET Framework version before 4.6, you fill have compile errors.

The Microsoft ML.NET can only be used for .NET Standard 2.0 compatible platforms, this includes .NET Framework 4.6.1 or later (including v4.7/4.7.1/4.7.2/4.8) and .NET Core 2.0 or later (including 2.1/2.2/3.0/3.1 and the incoming 5.0).

See this dependency notes on Microsoft.ML nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ML/):

[image: ML.NET dependency]

This also means if you use ML.NET with projects targeted to .NET Framework before v4.6, it is not guaranteed to work well.

Therefore I suggest you to target your project to use .NET Framework at least v4.7.2, because the .NET Framework 4.6.x and before is not supported anymore.

Comment: Well i tried using 4.72 but no-go That's why i was looking for an reference/example project/